# Issue in dropbox-android-sync-sdk-1.0

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

Below code in `onClickLinkToDropbox()` method in `HelloDropboxActivity` class of "Hello Dropbox" example in [Android Sync SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xiw2rsk3hcjcney/jeDsth_hUD) show error as

> The type `android.app.Fragment` cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required `.class` files.

How can I solve this ? I'm using Android 2.3.3.

```
mDbxAcctMgr.startLink(this,REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the compiler being unreasonably picky during overload resolution.  I see two possible solutions to this:

1. Build with a later SDK version (11 or later).  You only need to change the SDK you use to build (set the target in Eclipse project properties dialog, or target=android-11 in project.properties).  You can leave both minimum and target set to 10 in your AndroidManifest.xml, so your app will still be compatible with older versions.  In general it should always be safe to build with the latest SDK.  You'll get warnings if you use APIs which don't exist in your manifest-defined target.
2. Work around it by forcing the overload resolution like this:
   `mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);`

Comment: `mDbxAcctMgr.startLink((Activity)this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);` is worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

> If you're not already using it, you will also need the Android Support library. In Eclipse, open the context menu on your project and select Android Tools → Add support library... and follow the prompts to add the library to your project.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/tutorial/android

Comment: I have added `Android Support library`

Comment: do you use the latestet version (v4) of it?

Comment: is your target up to date? (target=android-16)

Comment: no.`target=android-10` i'm developing app for device with android v2.3.3. so i'm using `API-10`. can i build my app with `API-16` and use in devices with android v2.3.3 ?

Comment: you can and should. set te targetSdkVersion in the AndroidManifest.xml to 16 and the target in the project.properties to android-16.